# Memory exhausted when uploading images

Tags: ee2, file-uploads, php, image, fatal

I am breaking my head with this issue for several days.

I am using Expression Engine 2.11.1

When trying to upload an image using the File Upload feature, I am getting the following error

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 4251572 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 100 bytes) in /srv/XXXXXXXXXX/public_html/site/zocalo/cm/codeigniter/system/libraries/Image_lib.php on line 1255
```

Everyone will say that my php.ini is low on memory but I have set everything correctly. Here my php.ini setup

`memory_limit = 200M
max_execution_time = 300
max_input_time = 60
log_errors_max_len = 1024
post_max_size = 8M
upload_max_filesize = 100M
max_file_uploads = 20`

The problem is that my pictures are **2KB** and **100x100pixels**. See images attached.

Any idea how I can fix this?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What about uploading other kinds of images (JPEG, GIF)? What about other directories?

Answer (score 1):

Your php.ini could be overridden somewhere.

Check `Tools > Utilities > PHP Info` to see if there are any local values that don't match your php.ini

If you're on Apache try looking for a .htaccess file in the EE root or in any Virtual Host configurations you may have.